# ionic 2 with php msql

Tags: php, mysql, ionic2

```
My Login.php file


<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_database = "test";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $aemp=$_REQUEST['user'];
    ?>
```

my login.html file

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.userName" placeholder="Enter your username">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Enter yourPassword">
  </label>
</div>
<button ng-click="login()" class="button button-outline button-stable" >
```

My mainserver.js file

```
app.service('mainService',function ($http,$q) {

    this.login = function (userInfo) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.post('http://localhost/login.php',{user:userInfo})
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.records;
            if(res){
                defer.resolve(response);
            }else{
                defer.reject(response);
            }
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        })
        return defer.promise
    }

})
```

when i am sending object to my php file its shows me 

user obj  Object {userName: "asdas", password: "sadsaada"}
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/login.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the **js** file

```
app.service('mainService',function ($http,$q) {
    this.login = function (userInfo) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.post(
            'http://localhost/login.php',
            {user: userInfo},
            {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}}
        )
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.records;
            if(res){
                defer.resolve(response);
            }else{
                defer.reject(response);
            }
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        })
        return defer.promise
    }

});
```

and on the server side in **php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, accept");
```

Comment: thanks mate issue is on server side and now it is resolved :)